# using python to convert datetime to integer for NVD3 plotting

Tags: python, nvd3.js

I'm using python to make a NVD3 chart with date on the x-axis.
I recently noticed that on one machine it show the date 2017-March and on another machine with another timezone it shows 2017-Feb instead.

I used:

```
x = datetime(2017, 3, 1)
1000 * int(time.mktime(x.timetuple()))
1488355200000L
```

also tried:

```
1000*(x-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
1488326400000.0
```

both are off by a month.
In javascript, I tried:

```
var x = new Date(2017 , 3, 1);
x.getTime();
1491030000000
```

which is a bigger number so it might be the correct answer but I don't the the equivalent in python.
Does anyone know how to correct this?
and why does it appear differently on different machines with different timezones by one month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, `datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)`, and parameter month should be `1 <= month <= 12`.

Your code `x = datetime(2017, 3, 1)`,  the time is `2017-03-01 00:00:00`, it is March.

In JS, `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`, and parameter month should be `0 <= month <= 11`.

Your code `var x = new Date(2017, 3, 1);`, the time is `2017-04-01 00:00:00`, it is April not March.

And, when you convert the second to milliseconds in python, better multiple float format 1000.0 not int format.

---

update

To make it work, I had to add a day. It's an edge case problem. It was NOT related to floating point:

```
    A_DAY = 86400000
    xdata = A_DAY + 1000 * (x.replace(tzinfo=None)-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: @max Thanks for your update, hope it will help others as well.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying why there was a discrepancy :)